# Swift - downcast NSURLResponse to NSHTTPURLResponse in order to get response code

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building rest queries in SWIFT using NSURLRequest

```
var request : NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

var connection : NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
connection.start()
```

My question is how to do i get response code out of the response that is returned:

```
    func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
//...
}
```

According to Apple:  `NSHTTPURLResponse` which is a subclass of `NSURLResponse` has a status code but I'm not sure how to downcast my response object so i can see the response code.

This doesn't seem to cut it:

```
println((NSHTTPURLResponse)response.statusCode)
```

Thanks

Comment: I think that is a *downcast*, not an *upcast*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use an optional cast (`as?`) with optional binding (`if let`):

```
func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        println(httpResponse.statusCode)
    } else {
        assertionFailure("unexpected response")
    }
}
```

or as a one-liner

```
let statusCode = (response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? -1
```

where the status code would be set to `-1` if the response is not an HTTP response
(which should not happen for an HTTP request).