# How to get the status code from HTTP Get in swift?

Tags: ios, http, swift

I have try the following code to implement HTTP Get in IOS Swift.

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in

            var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
            println("response = \(response)")
        })
```

It success and show the following response:

```
response = <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x155xxxxx> { URL: http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:38080/getid/user-wiced1 } 
{ status code: 200, headers {
    "Content-Length" = 111;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Thu, 08 Jan 2015 07:31:21 GMT";
    Server = "spray-can/1.3.2-20140909";
} }
```

How to get the `status code` from `NSURLResponse` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634539/swift-downcast-nsurlresponse-to-nshttpurlresponse-in-order-to-get-response-cod.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`NSURLResponse` do not have status code, but `NSHTTPURLResponse` does. So cast it:

```
let httpResponse = response as NSHTTPURLResponse
httpResponse.statusCode
```

Comment: Is it mean change the type of `response` to the `NSHTTPURLResponse` , and get the statusCode?

Comment: You do not "change" the type by casting. As your print show the type is already `NSHTTPURLResponse`, but your are using it superclass interface `NSURLResponse`. You need to change interface by casting to access status code.