# Get http response status code of URLSession.shared.dataTask

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I request a web page with this code

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: url)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

if error == nil && data != nil {
// No error
}else{
// Error
if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
  print(httpResponse.statusCode)
 }
}
```

I am trying to get the error code when requesting a page by casting the response to `HTTPURLResponse` but the cast dose not work and the print is not executed. Do you know how can I get the code?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382505/how-do-you-test-a-url-and-get-a-status-code-in-swift-3

Comment: I saw  it before posting the question, there is no answer for my problem

Answer (score 1):

Your `if let httpResponse` code runs only in the `else` branch of the error checking `if` statement. You might also want to check the response in such cases when no error has occurred.

Answer (score -1):

I needed a solution to this and here is the code I got to through a lot of testing:

```
func getChuckNorrisDat() async -> String{           
     var data: Data? = nil
     var response: HTTPURLResponse? = nil
            
     do {
           (data, response) = try await (URLSession.shared.data(from: URL(string:"https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random-")!) as? (Data, HTTPURLResponse))!
         // catches errors in response from web api -- so web api has been
         // successfully contacted but a "normal" status error occurs
         // Other bad errors throw exceptions which is caught below
         // bad URL like string:"https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random-"
      // real URL is https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random (no dash at end)
         // will cause this error (404)
         switch response?.statusCode{
             case _ where response!.statusCode < 200 || response!.statusCode >= 300:
             return "Couldn't carry on.  Bad status code from API \(response?.statusCode)"
             default:
                print("Success!")
            }
        }
        catch{
                // catches errors when the URL is not well formed
                // bad URL like the following causes this exception:
                // (notice the x in the protocol portion of URL
                // string:"httpxs://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random"
                print("!! What ERROR? \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return "\(error.localizedDescription)"
            }
    return "failed!"
}
```

First thing I do is set up the two variables `data` and `response` to hold the returned values from the call to the `data()` method.

Notice that we have to cast the `response` to a `HTTPURLResponse` so we will have the `.statusCode` property available.

The rest is explained in the code sample.
This works great.

Comment: Lots of issues here. 1) You have some `return` statements but not on all code paths and the function isn't declared to have a return value. 2) The function needs to be declared as `async`. 3) Won't the code crash due to the force-unwraps if the response isn't actually an `HTTPURLResponse`?

Comment: @HangarRash It was an oversight, because I had copied and slightly altered from my actual code to simplify for this example. I fixed it so, 1) all paths return a string 2) method declared `async` 3) what else would the `data` method return?  In what case would it ever not return the `HTTPURLResponse`?  How would you handle that?

Comment: I don't know a specific case where the response is not an `HTTPURLResponse` but Swift makes it easy to work with optionals without the need to resort to forced-unwraps.

Comment: That is true, except once you know that an optional will be fulfilled in a specific way then you can use the ! operator.  For example, if you've checked that the optional isn't nil then you can use the ! operator.

Comment: Yes but 1) Swift makes it easy avoid it, 2) your code isn’t ensuring it’s not nil before the force unwrapping.